# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with possibly nonsymmetrical proposal matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $S$ be a finite set, $\mu$ a probability distribution on $S$ with $\mu(x)>0$ for all $x \in S$.

Let $(q(x,y))_{x,y \in S}$ be a stochastic matrix ($q(x,y) \geq 0 \forall x,y \in S$ and $\sum_{y \in S} q(x,y)=1 \forall x \in S$).

Show that the matrix defined by $P=(p(x,y))_{x,y \in S}$ also is a stochastic matrix for

$$p(x,y)=q(x,y)\cdot \min\Big(1, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)}\Big) \text{, for } y \neq x$$

My attempt:

The condition $p(x,y)\geq 0 \forall x,y \in S$ is clear.

The second condition:

If $1$ is always the minimal value this follows from $(q(x,y))$ being stochastic.
If the other value is always minimal, we have
$$\sum_{y\in S}p(x,y)=\sum_{y \in S}q(x,y)\cdot \min \Big(1, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)}\Big)=\sum_{y \in S} \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)}=\frac{1}{\mu(x)} \sum_{y \neq x} \mu(y)q(y,x)=\frac{\mu(x)}{\mu(x)}=1$$

But I do not really understand what happens when the minima are mixed.

My most promising result is the condition:

$$1=\sum_{y \in S}p(x,y)=\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)}<1}\frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)}+\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} \geq 1}q(x,y)$$

$$\iff$$

$$\mu(x)=\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)}<1}\mu(y)q(y,x)+\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} \geq 1}\mu(x)q(x,y)$$

We can include the equality to $1$ of the fraction in either of the sums, it does not change anything. Then I have:

$$\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} \leq 1}\mu(y)q(y,x)+\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} > 1}\mu(x)q(x,y) \leq$$

$$\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} \leq 1}\mu(x)q(x,y)+\sum_{y \in S, \frac{\mu(y)q(y,x)}{\mu(x)q(x,y)} > 1}\mu(x)q(x,y)=\mu(x)$$

But I cannot give $\mu(x)$ as a lower bound.

Any insight is welcome!

Comment: One question, I think that you are assuming $q(x,x)=0$ in your first and second attempt which is a restrictive supplementary condition that isn't stated before, but the condition $q(x,y) \forall y\in S$ seems to contradict this. Have I missed something here ? Anyway in the first attempt correcting this (i.e. adding $q(x,x)$ in the sum) leads to the same result.

Comment: Second point the definition of $p(x,x)$ is left open, unless mistaken, but $p(x,x)$  is needed to check wether $p$ is a stochastic matrix or not, unless mistaken. regards

Comment: @thebridge You are correct regarding $q(x,x)$. I am not sure what $p(x,x)$ is, but I assume it stays at $q(x,x)$. Will edit soon.

Comment: @TheBridge I have edited the question assuming $p(x,x)=q(x,x)$, so it is now included in the sum which includes equality to $1$ of the ratio.

Comment: The mixed case with $S=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mu=\{p_1=0.20,p_2=1-p_1=0.80\}$, $Q=\{q_{11}=0.70,q_{12}=1-q_{11}=0.30,q_{21}=1-q_{22}=0.40,q_{22}=0.60\}$ shows that $P$ is not in general stochastic matrix (I get  $P=\{p_{11}=0.70,p_{12}=1-q_{11}=0.30,p_{21}0.075,q_{22}=0.60\}$ unless mistaken so that the second line doesn't sum to $1$ though respecting your conditions. So I think that $q(x,x)$ is the degree of freedom needed so that all sum along  lines of $P$ is 100% and P a stochastic matrix. Regards

Comment: @TheBridge Second checked your calculation, you are right, thank you. So you mean that $q(x,x)$ is determined afterwards to fill what is missing? So the upper bound I delivered would be enough to give a stochastic matrix? If you want, you can post it as an answer and I will accept!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant ! No need to post an answer for this you have got your answer this is what matters